# How to unwind jsonb array into object per jsonb column based on object id?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given an existing data structure similar to the following:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample (id int, metadata_array jsonb, text_id_one jsonb, text_id_two jsonb);
INSERT INTO sample
VALUES ('1', '[{"id": "textIdOne", "data": "foo"},{"id": "textIdTwo", "data": "bar"}]'), ('2', '[{"id": "textIdOne", "data": "baz"},{"id": "textIdTwo", "data": "fiz"}]');
```

I'm trying to unwind the jsonb array of objects from an existing *metadata* column into new jsonb columns in the same table; that I've already created based on the known fixed list of id keys being `textIdOne`, `textIdTwo`, etc.

I thought I was close using `jsonb_populate_recordset()` but then realized that will populate columns per all the jsonb object's keys; not what I want. Desired result is object per column based on object id.

The only other tricky part of this operation is that my JSON object's `id` values use `camelCase` and it seems one should avoid quoted/cased column names, BUT I don't mind quoting or modifying the column names as a means to an end & once the update query is completed I can manually change the column names as needed.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.5.2

Existing data & structure:

```
id | metadata_array jsonb                             | text_id_one jsonb | text_id_two jsonb
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | [{"id": "textIdOne"...}, {"id": "textIdTwo"...}] | NULL              | NULL
2  | [{"id": "textIdOne"...}, {"id": "textIdTwo"...}] | NULL              | NULL
```

Desired result:

```
id | metadata_array jsonb     | text_id_one jsonb      | text_id_two jsonb
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | [{"id": "textIdOne",...  | {"id": "textIdOne"...} | {"id": "textIdTwo"...}
2  | [{"id": "textIdOne",...  | {"id": "textIdOne"...} | {"id": "textIdTwo"...}
```

---

**Clarifications:**

Thanks for the answers thus far everyone! Though I do know the complete list of keys (about 9) I cannot count on the ordering being consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of the json arrays contain two elements for the two new columns then use fixed paths like in dmfay's answer. Otherwise you should unnest the arrays using [jsonb_array_elements()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) twice, for `text_id_one` and `text_id_two` separately.

```
update sample t set
    text_id_one = value1,
    text_id_two = value2
from sample s, 
    jsonb_array_elements(s.metadata_array) as e1(value1),
    jsonb_array_elements(s.metadata_array) as e2(value2)
where s.id = t.id
    and value1->>'id' = 'textIdOne'
    and value2->>'id' = 'textIdTwo'
returning t.*
```

[Test the query in SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/83f36/1)

In case of more than two elements of the arrays this variant may be more efficient (and more convenient too):

```
update sample t
set 
    text_id_one = arr1->0,
    text_id_two = arr2->0
from (
    select 
        id,
        jsonb_agg(value) filter (where value->>'id' = 'textIdOne') as arr1,
        jsonb_agg(value) filter (where value->>'id' = 'textIdTwo') as arr2
    from sample,
    jsonb_array_elements(metadata_array)
    group by id
    ) s
where t.id = s.id
returning t.*
```

[SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/83f36/1)

Answer (score 0):

You said the id list is 'fixed'; is the ordering of objects in `metadata_array` consistent? You can do that with plain traversal:

```
UPDATE sample
   SET text_id_one = metadata_array->0,
       text_id_two = metadata_array->1;
```

Comment: I cannot count on the ordering being consistent; I've updated the question with this clarification :-)